# What is the difference between single digit range and 2 numbers range?

Tags: python, range

This is probably a silly question, but I just want to know what is different when we use:

```
for i in range 10:
```

and when we say:

```
for I in range(0, 9):
```

Comment: Have you read the manual? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer They are not the same. The first loop iterates 10 times and the second iterates 9 times.

Comment: The first is also a syntax error…

Comment: The first one needs a parenthesis around 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its easy to experiment in the python shell

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(i)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> for i in range(0,9):
...     print(i)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

And help is only a few keystrokes away

```
>>> help(range)

Help on class range in module builtins:

class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
 |  
 |  Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)
 |  to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.
 |  start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.
 |  These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
 |  When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid (Syntax error):
`for i in range 10:`

You can do something like this, however:
`for i in range (10):` (generates numbers 0-9 (inclusive))

And this, as you have it
`for I in range(0, 9):` (generates numbers 0-8 (inclusive))

Comment: You make it sound like there's no single-argument version of `range`…

Comment: You can use a pair of parenthesis around 10.

Comment: @ProChess yes, with the parenthesis, it will be fine, but without them, it's an error

Comment: @deceze I see what you mean, I will edit my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you need to edit your answer. The correct way to do is to use `for i in range(10):` or `for i in range(0,10):`

Answer (score 1):

When You use `i in range(10)`:
It will starting with 0 and end-1 that means 9

OP:

```
0
1
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9
```

**It will always take default as 0**

When you use `i in range(0,9)`

It will start with 0 and the end point is 8-1

**start end-1**

OP:

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8
```

When you use`i in range(0,2,10)`

It will start with 0 ,it will skip by 2 and the end point is 10-1

**start step end-1**

OP:

```
0 
2 
4 
6 
8
```